# How do I update 1 table in the database in Doctrine/Symfony?

Tags: php, session, doctrine, symfony

I want to use doctrine sessions (from https://packagist.org/packages/shapecode/doctrine-session-handler-bundle), however, as part of the Symfony project, I am using an already existing (populated from another source as well as the Symfony project) database. I just want to add the table in there to do the sessions. As part of the documentation, I am supposed to run the code:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

However, that comes back with:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception]
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

So I want to use this method to only update what is required for the sessions. Is this possible?

Comment: Check your doctrine entities, you are most likely trying to create two tables with the same name. Taking a look at the package, there is a Session class in the Entity folder. Maybe you have a class with the same name or table annotation with name "session"?

Comment: This is true, however, because I have no control over the database for the main tables in this project, I just want to be able to let doctrine create the session table and I will manually deal with the rest. The other option I guess is manually create the Session table and don't let Doctrine do anything with table creation or updating.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mention in the comments that you have a `session` table.

If you do then it will fail because this bundle tries to create `session` table. There also seem to be problems with some database drivers since "session" can be a reserved word.

There's a very recent [open issue](https://github.com/shapecode/doctrine-session-handler-bundle/issues/2) relat.... oh it's you that opened it!

Well hopefully you've found the source of your problem now.

Comment: Yeh, I was aware of this problem, but that's not the issue with forcing changes to the database. I have views (need I say more) that I am pulling from that will of course be 1 way information flow. When you try to force changes to the database it wants everything to be a table. I just want to manually deal with all views and only map the one table (which is now fixed in dev 2.0 to not be session) so that the rest can operate as is and I can change them manually if required.